# ASP.NET Treeview control supporting drag & drop?

Tags: asp.net, custom-server-controls

Can anybody recommend a treeview component for ASP.NET that supports drag & drop (between it's own nodes - it's for a content management system to rearrage the pages). Don't mind if it's open source or commercial (can't quite stretch to the [treeview from Telerik](http://demos.telerik.com/ASPNET/Prometheus/Treeview/Examples/Functionality/DragAndDropNodes/DefaultCS.aspx) though). Shame..

Any other options? Thanks.

Comment: Any way to do same thing in WINDOWS ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you could stretch to including jQuery (free) then there is a client side tree that does drag drop [jstree](http://jstree.com/jsTree/examples/_opers/moving.html). You would just need to implement ajax hooks to handle the database updates for the tree structure.

Answer (score 1):

[Obout.com's treeview looks slick](http://www.obout.com/t2/edraganddrop.aspx).  I've never used it, but I've thought about it many a time...

Answer (score 1):

Telerik is the way forward my friend!
Have you not got a copy from the NxtGenUG yet?

Comment: +1 Yeah, got Telerik now thanks, question specifes 'not telerik' though so you don't get the answer sorry.. :) No treeview in MVC stuff yet: http://www.telerik.com/products/aspnet-mvc.aspx

Comment: No but the Telerik tree view is fantastic! Drag/drop, multi select, context menus!

Comment: +1 for pointing out the telerik mvc controls, missed those!
Sweet